# How to pass multiple connection to birt Report?

Tags: java, birt

I can pass database connection to report via java code. Following is how I implemented:

```
DataSource datasourceOracle= (DataSource)initialContext.lookup("java:jboss/jdbc/BirtConn");
task.getAppContext().put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection", datasourceOracle.getConnection());
```

My problem is the report is using multiple datasource. So I need to pass two multiple connection to report. How can I?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the details of your connections inside your Java code, you could pass these details instead of just the JNDI names, like this:

```
task.getAppContext().put("conn1.username", "scott");
task.getAppContext().put("conn1.password", "tiger");
task.getAppContext().put("conn1.url", "oracle:jdbc:thin:@//oracledb:1521/orcl");

task.getAppContext().put("conn2.username", "hr");
task.getAppContext().put("conn2.password", "x");
task.getAppContext().put("conn2.url", "oracle:jdbc:thin:@//other-db:1521/xyz");
```

Inside the report, you can then use the dataset's property binding dialog to set the values from the context, e.g. for your first data source:

```
Database URL: reportContext.getAppContext().get("conn1.name");
User Name:    reportContext.getAppContext().get("conn1.username");
Password:     reportContext.getAppContext().get("conn1.password");
```